# Trying to fill data of table from another table using a procedure, Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 keeps popping up

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
CREATE TABLE temp_t (
shipper_id integer,
shipper_name varchar(100),
shipper_contact_details varchar(30), 
product_id integer,
vehicle_maker varchar(100),
vehicle_model varchar(100),
vehicle_color varchar(100),
vehicle_model_year integer,
vehicle_price decimal(7,2),
quantity integer,
    discount decimal (2,2),
customer_id varchar(30),
customer_name varchar(100),
gender varchar(100),
job_title varchar(100),
phone_number varchar(100),
email_address varchar(100),
city varchar(100),
country varchar(100),
state varchar(100),
customer_address varchar(100),
order_date varchar(100),
order_id integer,
ship_date varchar(100),
ship_mode varchar(100),
shipping varchar (100),
postal_code integer,
credit_card_type varchar (100),
credit_card_number varchar(100),
customer_feedback varchar(100),
quarter_number integer,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id)                    
);     

create table vehicles_t (
vehicle_maker varchar(20),
vehicle_model varchar(20),
vehicle_color varchar(15),
vehicle_model_year integer,
vehicle_price decimal(7,2),
quantity integer,
    quarter_number integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_maker)
    );
```

creating my two tables to fill

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS vehicles_p;

-- Syntax to create a stored procedure-
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE vehicles_p()
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO vehicles_t(
vehicle_maker,
vehicle_model,
vehicle_color,
vehicle_model_year,
vehicle_price,
quantity,
    quarter_number            
) SELECT * FROM temp_t;
END;
```

creating a procedure so i can automate the filling of other tables using temp_t table as base.

```
TRUNCATE temp_t;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/Users/***/Downloads/new_wheels_sales_qtr_1.csv" -- change this location to load another week
INTO TABLE temp_t
FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;'
```

call vehicles_p();

fills temp_t table with values from a csv so the procedure can work,and then i call for the procedure. This is where the error occurs.

Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

You have sql code which creates a table temp_t with a specific set of fields.

You create (but do not execute) a procedure.

Then you run sql code that populates a CSV into temp_t (presumably with a matchine field list).

Then you run the procedure which is expected to take fields from the temp_t table and populate them into the (previously unmentioned and undescribed) vehicles_t table.

The system complains that you have (at this point) the wrong field count to be able to run the INSERT INTO sql code.

This is because you are pulling "*" (which includes ALL the fields from temp_t) in your insert command rather than a field list which must match the fields in your INSERT INTO sql code.

I can't say it will succeed at that point, as I've not seen the structure of vehicles_t. But if those fields match (field count as well as data types), you should be good.